# Sci-Fi movie about a black man alone in spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship, space

I think it was an English movie and set in modern world.

The movie is only about the one black guy (astronaut) in the spaceship, who is on a mission to reach some planet (maybe Jupiter? from what I remember), and he is alone. He decides to continue the mission and rejects the idea of landing on Earth after spending months alone on the spaceship.

Answer (score 16):

[Astronaut: The Last Push](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1541123/) (2012)

> When a tragic accident cuts short the first manned mission to explore
>   life on the moons of Jupiter, Michael Forrest must make the 3 year
>   journey home to Earth in pure solitude.

---

Trailer:

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the correct movie. I knew a famous actor was there, but I could't remember his face and continue seeking.
And correct, it was Lance Henriksen (alias Bishop from Aliens, and other Movies like 'Mindripper').

Comment: FYI, the video is no longer available

Answer (score -4):

This is probably "[Astronaut: The Last Push](https://www.habitablezone.com/2014/11/16/astronaut-the-last-push/)." [image: Movie Poster]

Comment: Please provide some details as to why you think this movie matches the description.

Comment: Google it for yourself.  It is a very close fit.

Comment: Sorry, but that's just how things work here on StackExchange. You need to provide detail on why it fits, at the very least a link to an outside source (sometimes that's not enough). Otherwise it's not considered a good answer and can even get downvoted.

Comment: Votes are irrelevant.  The correct answer will be seen by the person who asked it.

Comment: okay, if that's how you feel...but why ask a question here just to have to google it yourself anyway? How hard is it to copy/paste a summary/link? See for yourself how many users post what I posted on one line answers.

Comment: In the end, I'm just giving you some advice. Do with it what you will.

Comment: In fact have a look at [one of your own answers here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73599/trying-to-recall-a-story-involving-two-observers-in-space-stations-who-kill-an-a/73635#73635). See what Richard posted as a comment? How Sean Duggan added detail to your one line answer?

Comment: If you won't play by the rules, why bother playing at all?

Comment: @DoscoJones Site etiquette says votes do matter. You should probably finish the edit I started on your answer.

Comment: @TrishLing ^_^ I only added a very irrelevant comment to the question. Major Stackings did the edit.