# Story: AI-proof communication by playing music

Tags: story-identification

Two spaceships are in a dire situation. The pilots want to communicate with each other to plan how to escape (or maybe defeat) a nearby AI ship. When they communicate by speaking, the AI easily understands and jams their communication. However they can communicate by playing music (pop songs, classical etc.) from their ships' digital library.

Comment: Can we please have some details? Is this a written story? Is it a short story, or part of a novel? Roughly which decade is it from? Was it in English? Etc...

Comment: This makes me think of Saberhagen and the Beverley stories

Comment: No berserkers named Beverly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Tin Ear](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?95757), Spider Robinson, the [Antinomy](https://books.google.com/books/about/Antinomy.html?id=Rh61AAAACAAJ) anthology, 1980.

Two human warship pilots have to defeat an alien berserker-type ship by playing music to each other.

> I keyed in the early twenty-first-century Revivalist dirge "Is There a Hole in Your Bucket" and hoped he wouldn't think I was requesting a damage report.
>
> He responded with the late twenty-first-century anti-Revivalist ballad "The Sky Ain't Holy No More."

If correct then this is a duplicate [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73599/trying-to-recall-a-story-involving-two-observers-in-space-stations-who-kill-an-a).